Getting error with subquery in SQL server
Find the total number of people present inside the hospital?
create table hospital (
    emp_id int
    , action varchar(10)
    , time datetime
);

insert into hospital values ('1', 'in', '2019-12-22 09:00:00');
insert into hospital values ('1', 'out', '2019-12-22 09:15:00');
insert into hospital values ('2', 'in', '2019-12-22 09:00:00');
insert into hospital values ('2', 'out', '2019-12-22 09:15:00');
insert into hospital values ('2', 'in', '2019-12-22 09:30:00');
insert into hospital values ('3', 'out', '2019-12-22 09:00:00');
insert into hospital values ('3', 'in', '2019-12-22 09:15:00');
insert into hospital values ('3', 'out', '2019-12-22 09:30:00');
insert into hospital values ('3', 'in', '2019-12-22 09:45:00');
insert into hospital values ('4', 'in', '2019-12-22 09:45:00');
insert into hospital values ('5', 'out', '2019-12-22 09:40:00');

My Solution
select emp_id, max(time) as total_in
from hospital
where action = 'in'
group by emp_id
having max(time) > ANY (
    select emp_id, max(time)
    from hospital
    where action = 'Out'
    group by emp_id
);

Please explain to me why am getting this error

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

while running the above query in SQL server even though am using ANY multiple row operator with subquery.
answer should be emp_id 2,3,4.

Remove emp_id from the query you used in your ANY clause. You can't compare one column with two. Anyway, you will get a list, not a number, I guess you know that?

It looks like you need to compare the latest (max) "in" time with the latest (max) "out" time per employee. I expect you also need to handle the case where there are "in" rows but no "out" rows for a given employee.
There are a couple of ways to do this.
One is to build two subselects, one for "in" and one for "out", join them on emp_id, and compare the times.
select I.emp_id, I.latest_in
from (
    select emp_id, max(time) as latest_in
    from hospital
    where action = 'In'
    group by emp_id
) I
left join (
    select emp_id, max(time) as latest_out
    from hospital
    where action = 'Out'
    group by emp_id
) O ON O.emp_id = I.emp_id
where (I.latest_in > O.latest_out or O.latest_out is null);

A left join is used to handle cases where an employee has "in" rows but no "out" rows.  If we cared about employees with "out" rows but no "in" rows, we could have used a full outer join.
Another way is to use conditional aggregation to calculate the latest in and latest out in the same subquery. Conditional aggregation just places a conditional IIF() function or CASE expression inside the aggregation function - in this case MAX(). If the condition returns a value, it is included in the aggregation. If it does not, the explicit or implicit NULL is ignored.
select IO.emp_id, IO.latest_in
from (
    select
        emp_id,
        max(case when action = 'In' then time end) as latest_in,
        max(case when action = 'Out' then time end) as latest_out
    from hospital
    group by emp_id
) IO
where (IO.latest_in > IO.latest_out or IO.latest_out is null);

Both produce the same results.



emp_id
latest_in




2
2019-12-22 09:30:00.000


3
2019-12-22 09:45:00.000


4
2019-12-22 09:45:00.000



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
To just get the count of people still in the hospital, you can replace the select list in either of the above to just select count(*) as total_in. For the sample data, the result would be 3.

You can make a query to get all the maximum values of time by employee and check if the action is 'in'.
It will return you the last action of the employee, if it is 'in' it means the employee is still inside the hospital.
select h.emp_id, h.time
from hospital as h
where time = (
select MAX(time) from hospital as h2 where h2.emp_id = h.emp_id
) and h.action = 'in'


